# Expand X macro inside another macro

Tags: c, macros, x-macros

I have a function that prints an output using `fprintf()`, and it uses a macro both for the format string and the parameters. Since there are several places printing this info, this allows expanding the print while changing only one place.

I want to generate a different print using the same data, but I want them to automatically expand together using an X-macro, but I can't get it to compile. I don't want there to be a need to edit the print every time I add something to print, or to wrap each print in ugly `#define`s.

This program attempts to do what I want, but it doesn't compile:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define X(_a, _b, _c) \
    _a,

#define TABLE \
    X("abc", "123", "ddd") \
    X("def", "456", "aaa") \
    X("ghi", "789", "ddd") \
    
#define STUFF \
    TABLE

#undef X
    
int main()
{
    printf(" %s %s %s\n", STUFF);

    return 0;
}
```

(Idea is that STUFF prints one thing, and at another place i'll do a STUFF2 with a different column of the X macro called TABLE)

I get the following error:

> main.c: In function ‘main’:
>
> main.c:7:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘X’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
>
> ```
> X("abc", "123", "ddd") \
>
> ^
> ```
>
> main.c:12:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘TABLE’
>
> ```
> TABLE
>
> ^~~~~
> ```
>
> main.c:18:27: note: in expansion of macro ‘STUFF’
>
> ```
> printf(" %s %s %s\n", STUFF);
>
>                       ^~~~~
> ```
>
> main.c:8:5: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘X’
>
> ```
> X("def", "456", "aaa") \
>
> ^
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > main.c:7:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘X’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

Well, yes.  At line 18, where macro `STUFF` appears, it is first expanded to

```
TABLE
```

, then that is rescanned.  `TABLE` being defined as a macro, it, too, is expanded, resulting in

```
X("abc", "123", "ddd") X("def", "456", "aaa") X("ghi", "789", "ddd")
```

, then *that* is rescanned.  But `X` is *not* defined as a macro (or as anything else) at that point, because you previously `undef`ined it.  That leaves you with code that resembles three calls to an unknown function, without any kind of operator or separator between.  It is invalid.

Your X macro has to be defined appropriately at the place where it is expanded.  It does not need to be defined at all at the place where it appears in another macro's expansion text.  You seem to have that backward.

---

As discussed in comments, the objective is to be able to define separate macros, for example `STUFF` and `STUFF2` that expand `TABLE` to consistent results that differ from each other.  This is as opposed to causing `STUFF` to expand as wanted by manipulating the definition of `X`.

This can be accomplished by changing the definition of `TABLE` so that it is a function-like macro taking another macro name as an argument:

```
#define TABLE(m) \
    m("abc", "123", "ddd") \
    m("def", "456", "aaa") \
    m("ghi", "789", "ddd")
```

The macros `STUFF` and `STUFF2` can then control the expansion by their choice of which macro name to pass to `TABLE()`:

```
#define X(_a, _b, _c) _a
#define Y(_a, _b, _c) _b
#define STUFF TABLE(X)
#define STUFF2 TABLE(Y)
```

Comment: As I wrote in the other answer, I basically want here an X macro that I can write once, and it expands exactly the same way in several different places. My approach might not be good, but is there another way to do it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, @gil_bz.  If you want it to expand the same way everywhere, then why not just leave it defined?  If you're concerned about a name collision that way, then choose a more distinctive name.  There's nothing particularly special about the name `X`.  It is the definition in scope at the point of use (whether direct or indirect) that matters.

Comment: In this example i have 3 columns in the X macro. So STUFF expands column 1, and STUFF2 would expand column 2. I don't want to have to re-define the X macro every time i use STUFF or STUFF2, since every instance of STUFF does exactly the same thing, so it is ugly to write out the X macro again every time.

Comment: @gil_bz, redefining the `X` macro every time you use the macro depending on it is *exactly* the standard usage paradigm for X macros.  Nevertheless, there is a way to accomplish what you're after, more or less.  I will update this answer shortly.

Comment: There you are, @gil_bz.

Comment: Thanks! This still suffers from not being able to ```#undef``` the X/Y, but i can overcome that by giving them less common names.

Comment: Minor nitpick: it doesn't actually work since you need to add commas at the end of the first 2 lines of TABLE.

Comment: @gil_bz, The absence of separators is carried forward from your original code. Whether you need or want commas or other delimiters, and which and where, depends on how you want to use the expanded result.  I took the question to be about the macro expansion problem generally, and that's what I answered.  Accordingly, I did not present a complete program in this answer.  I actually tested the specifics in a program where no delimiters are wanted inside the expansions.

Answer (score 1):

Undefining `X` before `STUFF` is expanded leads to … well `X` being undefined.

For X macro to work, you have to undefine *after* having used it in some non-macro code (so it can expand)

Once this is fixed, commas need to be moved in the list, else the last comma will trigger a syntax error (`error: expected ‘)’ before ‘X’`). Same thing for the last backslash of `TABLE`

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define X(_a, _b, _c) \
    _a

#define TABLE \
    X("abc", "123", "ddd"), \
    X("def", "456", "aaa"), \
    X("ghi", "789", "ddd")

#define STUFF \
    TABLE
int main()
{
    printf(" %s %s %s\n", STUFF);

#undef X


    return 0;
}
```

this compiles, executes and prints `abc def ghi`

Comment: I agree that this compiles, but since it un-defines X very late, it will mess with everything else using X. I suppose I can use some other random garbage name instead of X, and then I don't need to undefine at all (since the macro is defined in a .h file and used in several different .c files).

Comment: undefining X just before defining it again (and just after having used it in some construct that expands it) is the way. you cannot undefine X earlier. TABLE & STUFF depend on X definition. Macros don't expand when you define them, just when you _use_ them.

Comment: This suggested way, how can i define a STUFF2 that prints the second column? I can't define both STUFF and STUFF2 in the same .h file and have .c file use both of them. My specific use case requires only STUFF to be used more than once, but I don't see how this solves the problem in general.

Comment: you cannot define X in another macro. You have to define X again, and call STUFF again. The indirection between STUFF & TABLE is useless

Comment: Well the purpose of the question was not to write compilable code, but to find something that solves my problem, I just showed what I tried. So it doesn't feel like this answer helps me much unfortunately.